# Driving Dunedin to Queenstown early July

Tags: driving, new-zealand

What route should we take from Dunedin to Queenstown in winter?  No experience of driving on snow-covered or icy roads. Time not an issue. Have visited in Sept and Dec so expecting very different driving conditions.  Spending most of out 10 day road trip on east coast between Christchurch and Dunedin, before heading to Queenstown.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If time is not an issue, then just wait for the Transport Agency to clear the snow from the roads.

Comment: Would you consider taking a bus or flying, and then just renting in Queenstown?

Comment: There is unlikely to be snow on the roads between Dunedin and Queenstown, and ice probably only where there's no sun (overnight, early morning etc.)